# Is there a way to rank results using Hibernate's Criteria API?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, hql, criteria

I've got a query that's going to become very complicated and we would like to switch it to the Criteria API in order to keep it manageable. We basically select some data that matches filters but order the result set based on how many filters were matched. We do this by adding a field to the select clause that keeps track of how many filters match.

An example would be helpful:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90e02/2

Is there any way to do this using the Hibernate Criteria API. Our goal is to make sure this doesn't become code that creates a large HQL String that we have to maintain.

I don't necessarily need an example as an answer (though that would be great!) but a yes/no and something to point me to how it can be done would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another way to make this happen:

http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#selectCase%28%29) is the API to build an *SQL CASE* expression.

And here is some pseudo-code to do it:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...
javax.persistence.criteria.Expression rankExpression = 
        cb.sum(
              cb.selectCase().when(first_name = 'Carter',1).otherwise(0),
              cb.sum(cb.selectCase().when(last_name = 'Mason',1).otherwise(0),
                     cb.sum(...)
                     )
              );
```

Comment: I'm giving you an up vote but Expression is deprecated. I think I've found another (more complicated) way to do this.

Comment: hum... javax.persistence.criteria.Expression is part of JPA 2.0 and it don't seems deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Formula` annotation and put there `(CASE WHEN ... END)` expression for `rank` field.

Comment: This probably won't work because we need to be able to specify what the conditions are dynamically. The @Formula annotation only works if the conditions are known at compile time.

Comment: @Chris Williams You can use stored procedure in this case together with `@Formula` in this case.

Comment: thanks for the help. Stored procedures aren't on option for us and even if they were, we'd have to be able to pass in values to the stored procedure.